# can a method parameter pass an object by reference but be read-only?

Tags: c#, readonly, pass-by-reference

C#: can you make it so that a method parameter passes an object by reference but is read-only?

eg:

```
void MyMethod(int x, int y, read-only MyObject obj)
```

where `obj` is an object reference but this object cannot be modified during the method.

Can this be achieved in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why const parameters are not allowed in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263001/why-const-parameters-are-not-allowed-in-c)

Comment: That question asks why const parameters are not allowed.  My question asks whether a read-only parameter is possible in C#. I don't consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.  C# has no direct analogue to C++ `const` (its own const is something different).  A common C# pattern for this is to pass in a interface, such as `IEnumerable`, that does not permit modifications.  You can also create an immutable copy or wrapper.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Would I need to make MyObject implement the IEnumerable interface?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an example.  Think of the difference between `IEnumerable` and `List`.  You can clearly modify a `List`, but if you use it as an `IEnumerable` (which it implements), all you can do is access elements in order (`MoveNext`<->`Current`).  You can make your own interfaces with similar read-only properties.

Comment: +1, this is the same as my answer, I didn't see it. But I'll leave mine there as the "long version". :)

Answer (score 7):

If the class of the object you're passing was written by you, then you're in luck.

Ask yourself: if C# had a `const` feature, what operations on the object would I expect to be banned through a `const` reference to my class?

Then define an `interface` that leaves out the banned operations.

For example:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public string GetSomething() { ... }

    public void Clobber() { ... }

    public int Thing { get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

The corresponding "const" interface might be:

```
interface IConstMyClass 
{
    public string GetSomething() { ... }

    public int Thing { get { ... } }
}
```

Now amend the class:

```
class MyClass : IConstMyClass
{
```

Now you can use `IConstMyClass` to mean `const MyClass`.

```
 void MyMethod(int x, int y, IConstMyClass obj)
```

Note: there will be those who will tell you that this isn't enough. What if `MyMethod` casts back to `MyClass`? But ignore them. Ultimately the implementor can use reflection to get around any aspect of the type system - [see this amusing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230293/c-how-should-i-use-properties-when-dealing-with-listt-members/1232332#1232332).

The only option to stop reflection attacks is the trivial approach: make a totally disconnected clone.

Comment: Although another answer is essentially the same, I really appreciate the extra effort to explain it so well in a way that a CPP programmer would understand.  This answer is an outstanding effort which is very helpful.

Comment: @shawn1874 - thanks, what a great bit of feedback! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in C#.

You can prevent this by passing in an immutable object.

Comment: How you pass it is different from immutability, the two are completely orthogonal in the case of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism that does this for you.

Either pass a throwaway copy, or build immutability, even if temporary, into the class itself.

Comment: You mean like a clone of the original object?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if that is feasible. If you do, then changes doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the overhead of making your class implement the ICloneable interface?

Comment: I wouldn't, that is, I would make something similar, but I wouldn't implement ICloneable. It is a broken contract. As for overhead, it's another method, and depending on how the class has been written you might have to change parts of it to accomodate cloning. Runtime overhead should be zero though.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you make a copy of that object and do whatever you want with that copy while your `obj` remains not modified.

See here how to clone your object: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

Comment: One reason why you might not want to make a copy is because you're worried about the performance cost of making a copy.

Comment: I would prefer a solution that doesn't increase memory costs.

Comment: Another problem with that suggestion is that the coder who writes the "receiving" method may assume that the state changes they cause on the object will be permanent, when in fact they are going to be thrown away.

Comment: @Craig - the cost of temporary reference object allocation on the CLR is incredibly small, closer to stack allocation than C++ heap allocation. http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/the-amazing-speed-of-the-net-garbage-collector/

Comment: @Daniel: wouldn't it be a copy of the whole object, not just the reference?

Comment: @Daniel: I was hoping a modifier such as const or readonly could be used, which would alert the next coder who saw the method.

Comment: @Craig Johnston - "reference object" is what the CLR calls an object allocated from the GC heap, so yes, I'm talking about copying the object. The point is that you may be worrying about nothing. If it is expensive then the memory allocation won't be the expensive part - the cost is more likely to be in having to do a deep copy (which for some objects can involve modifying state external to the program, e.g. an object that encapsulates a temporary file).

Comment: @Craig - the type of the reference tells the coder what they can do to the object it refers to. It makes no difference whether this is done using a modifier keyword or a distinct hand-written interface. (Well, the difference is that you have to write the interface by hand, but otherwise its exactly the same).